# Cannot upload assets when Imagick is set as image driver

Tags: imagick

EDIT after resolving: offtopic since the issue was that the php extension for ImageMagick was not installed on the server - therefore not Craft-related.

Because .gif's were not being transformed properly (only the first frame) I figured ImageMagick was not doing the image transforms.

Therefore I updated the general config file with the line to set the imageDriver to ImageMagick ('imageDriver' => 'imagick'). However, as from that point whenever I tried to upload an asset in the control panel, the black loading bar appeared, instantly full, and the loading icon in the top right kept spinning. The loading bar did not disappear, nor did the file get uploaded.

As soon as I removed this line from the general config, the uploading worked as normal again.

I have tested my server and ImageMagick is installed (v6.8.3-6). I am running PHP 5.4.

I am not running any plugins. The only other setting I have in the general config file is 'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true

Does anybody know what could cause this issue? I would like to use ImageMagick for all the transfers, but of course especially for the .gif's.

Comment: Are you sure Imagick is enabled for PHP to use? If you go to `yourdomain.com/admin/utils/phpinfo` and search for imagick you should be able to see if there.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for the reply. I browsed to that link and searched for "imagick" on that page, but the search did not return any results. I have contacted my hosting provider and he confirms that ImageMagick is installed on the server with "standard implementation". When I click on the "Server Info" tab of the page you linked, I can see an orange triangle with exclamation mark in it next to "ImageMagick extension" (on hover it displays "Passed with warning").

Comment: If `imagick` doesn't show up when you go to `admin/utils/phpinfo`, then it's not available for PHP to use. They might have installed only the library, but not the PHP extension for it (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).

Comment: I have discussed this with my hosting provider and indeed the extension has not been installed. Unfortunately they are not willing to install it on the servers, so I guess I'll have to do without Imagick then. Thanks for the quick support though, Brad!

Comment: No worries... I'm going to go ahead and vote to close this, then.  Also, you should find a new hosting provider. ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the host is unwilling to install Imagick.